# Remove server side validation formatting changes on change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a function that validates input server side and sets the focus to the missing item and also make the item border red. This all works fin, I am struggling with how to handle removing the red border once the selected index has changed or the text box has a value? What is the best way to handle this? Javascript? I have tried the below javascript, but since the fields and dropdowns are located in usercontrols, I am not sure if this is corrrect. I have tried placing the javascript in both the server control ascx page and the aspx page where the submit button is.

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var companyRelation = document.getElementById('<%=ddlCompanyRelationship.ClientID %>');
            $('#ddlCompanyRelationship').change(function () {
                if (companyRelation.options.value != "-1") {
                    companyRelation.style.border = "#bebebe";
                }
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the page source and add javascript according to those methods if the ID is there then javascript on change function should trigger.

Javascript is client side so no need to paste it in server control page.
It would be easy if you give us a URL.

This document.getElementbyID with server side ID render may not help unless you tell us if it is actually giving you the ID from server to your client.

Can you paste the script you get in view source mode of your page.

Try using just jQuery to select that element and change its CSS to show another colour on change and use console.log to see if the event is actually triggering.

Comment: The issue I am running into is that the markup in the usercontrol is not in scope in the aspx page to be called for javascript validation?

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems working fine. The questions where to put JavaScript in control or in page then put it in control because you are going to use control on multiple pages which is main purpose of control, so instead on putting script on every page it's best practice to put it in control.

Now for border issue i have simple way.
Make one css class

```
.MakeBorderRed{ border-color: #ff0000 }
```

Then replace following code

```
if (companyRelation.options.value != "-1") 
{
    $('#ddlCompanyRelationship').addClass("MakeBorderRed");
}
else
{
    $('#ddlCompanyRelationship').removeClass("MakeBorderRed");
}
```